# insertion of structs into linked list hangs after 3 insertions

Tags: c, linked-list

i'm trying to implement a rudimentary context-free grammar parser in C.   i am still pretty new to C and trying to figure things out.

I want to parse a file of the following format:

```
RULE LEFT_HAND_SIDE RIGHT_HAND_SIDE
RULE2 LEFT_HAND_SIDE RIGHT_HAND_SIDE
etc
```

here's my code:

```
  while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s\n", type, LHS, RHS) == 3){

      if(!strcmp(type, "RULE") || !strcmp(type, "rule")){

          if(rules->head == NULL && rules->tail == NULL){

              rules->head = malloc(sizeof(Rule));
              rules->head = &(Rule) { 
                  .LHS = LHS,
                  .RHS = RHS,
                  .condition = "",
                  .next = NULL
              }; 
              rules->tail = rules->head;
          }
          else{

              Rule *curr;
              curr = rules->head;

              while(curr->next){
                  curr = curr->next;
              }

              curr->next = malloc(sizeof(Rule));
              curr->next = &(Rule) { 
                  .LHS = LHS,
                  .RHS = RHS,
                  .condition = "",
                  .next = NULL
              }; 
              rules->tail = curr->next;
          }
      } 
  }
```

when i run this program and input a file with 7 rules, it stops adding structs to the linked list after successfully inserting 3 rules, and just hangs.  i have no idea what's going on and have been stuck for a few hours now.

Comment: If you already maintain a `tail` pointer for your list, there's no need to start iterating from the start each time when you insert a node.

Comment: Please show us `type`, `LHS`, `RHS`....

Comment: @moffeltje I made the same comment and deleted, notice the indentation..... :-)

Comment: @moffeltje only for `RULE` the `if` will execute, for all other `RULE<n>`, `else` shuld execute...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The `else` belongs to the check whether the head and tail are `NULL`, not to the comparison with `"RULE"`.

Comment: @MOehm I blame the earlier (missing) indentation.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, I know, it is not easy to read someone else's poorly indented code. But that means that both your and moffeltje's now deleted commenst are valid, no?

Comment: @MOehm Yes, it appears so.

Comment: @MOehm Strange !! I cannot '@' tag moffeltje...why? I wanted to inform him about the misunderstanding. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, tagging works for me; I got notofied.

Comment: oh yea, sorry, the indentation is all screwed up.  

type, LHS, and RHS are all char arrays.  M Oehm, you're exactly right about the tail pointer, dumb oversight on my part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign the data to your node pointer:

```
    curr->next = malloc(sizeof(Rule));
    curr->next = &(Rule) { 
      .LHS = LHS,
      .RHS = RHS,
      .condition = "",
      .next = NULL
    };
```

you first allocate memory and then assign the pointer to the address of a local object with automatic storage, namely the one created with the compound literal. That means that you leak the allocated memory immediately, because you lose the only handle to it, and that your pointer will likely point to invalid memory once the local object goes out of scope. (And you will get an error when you try to `free` the memory later.)

If you want to initialise the freshly allocated with a compound literal, do this:

```
    curr->next = malloc(sizeof(Rule));
    *curr->next = (Rule) { 
      .LHS = LHS,
      .RHS = RHS,
      .condition = "",
      .next = NULL
    };
```

This creates a local object and copies its contents to the object pointed to by `curr->next`.

Comment: oh, i didn't know the compound literal initialized a scoped object with automatic storage.  thank you.  this fixed it perfectly.